# Panel aligned in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, panel

Guys I took the executable code that shiny provides and added another panel. How do I leave the second panel under the first? Is it possible ??? Thank you very much!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("bins",
                            "Number of bins:",
                            min = 1,
                            max = 20,
                            value = 30),
            ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an additional   `sidebarLayout` and     `sidebarPanel`. You can just put the second slider below the first. `tags$hr()` here is to visually separate them if you need to.

```
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      tags$hr(),
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 20,
                  value = 30)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Novica for the answer. One more thing like inserting text below the tags$ hr(). For example, I would like to say the following: "This is the second version)

Comment: @Jose yes you can do that. See the tags glossary here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html